# Navigating / scraping hashbang links with javascript (phantomjs)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, hashbang, phantomjs

I'm trying to download the HTML of a website that is almost entirely generated by JavaScript.  So, I need to simulate browser access and have been playing around with [PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/).  Problem is, the site uses hashbang URLs and I can't seem to get PhantomJS to process the hashbang -- it just keeps calling up the homepage.

The site is http://www.regulations.gov.  The default takes you to #!home.  I've tried using the following code (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490438/phantomjs-and-getting-modified-dom)) to try and process different hashbangs.

```
if (phantom.state.length === 0) {
     if (phantom.args.length === 0) {
        console.log('Usage: loadreg_1.js <some hash>');
        phantom.exit();
     }
     var address = 'http://www.regulations.gov/';
     console.log(address);
     phantom.state = Date.now().toString();
     phantom.open(address);

} else {
     var hash = phantom.args[0];
     document.location = hash;
     console.log(document.location.hash);
     var elapsed = Date.now() - new Date().setTime(phantom.state);
     if (phantom.loadStatus === 'success') {
             if (!first_time) {
                     var first_time = true;
                     if (!document.addEventListener) {
                             console.log('Not SUPPORTED!');
                     }
                     phantom.render('result.png');
                     var markup = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
                     console.log(markup);
                     phantom.exit();
             }
     } else {
             console.log('FAIL to load the address');
             phantom.exit();
     }
}
```

This code produces the correct hashbang (for instance, I can set the hash to '#!contactus') but it doesn't dynamically generate any different HTML--just the default page.  It does, however, correctly output that has when I call `document.location.hash`.

I've also tried to set the initial address to the hashbang, but then the script just hangs and doesn't do anything.  For example, if I set the url to `http://www.regulations.gov/#!searchResults;rpp=10;po=0` the script just hangs after printing the address to the terminal and nothing ever happens.

Comment: How is this related to Python?

Comment: Good point - I don't know why I put that tag there.

Comment: I tried it on windows. But probably, I got succeeded.

Comment: @mattn -- could you provide more information on what you did and if it worked?

Comment: i can see result.png is exist. and html appear. i don't get  hang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue here is that the content of the page loads asynchronously, but you're expecting it to be available as soon as the page is loaded.

In order to scrape a page that loads content asynchronously, you need to wait to scrape until the content you're interested in has been loaded. Depending on the page, there might be different ways of checking, but the easiest is just to check at regular intervals for something you expect to see, until you find it.

The trick here is figuring out what to look for - you need something that won't be present on the page until your desired content has been loaded. In this case, the easiest option I found for top-level pages is to manually input the H1 tags you expect to see on each page, keying them to the hash:

```
var titleMap = {
    '#!contactUs': 'Contact Us',
    '#!aboutUs': 'About Us'
    // etc for the other pages
};
```

Then in your success block, you can set a recurring timeout to look for the title you want in an `h1` tag. When it shows up, you know you can render the page:

```
if (phantom.loadStatus === 'success') {
    // set a recurring timeout for 300 milliseconds
    var timeoutId = window.setInterval(function () {
        // check for title element you expect to see
        var h1s = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
        if (h1s) {
            // h1s is a node list, not an array, hence the
            // weird syntax here
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(h1s, function(h1) {
                if (h1.textContent.trim() === titleMap[hash]) {
                    // we found it!
                    console.log('Found H1: ' + h1.textContent.trim());
                    phantom.render('result.png');
                    console.log("Rendered image.");
                    // stop the cycle
                    window.clearInterval(timeoutId);
                    phantom.exit();
                }
            });
            console.log('Found H1 tags, but not ' + titleMap[hash]);
        }
        console.log('No H1 tags found.');
    }, 300);
}
```

The above code works for me. But it won't work if you need to scrape search results - you'll need to figure out an identifying element or bit of text that you can look for without having to know the title ahead of time.

**Edit**: Also, it looks like the [newest version of PhantomJS](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface) now triggers an `onResourceReceived` event when it gets new data. I haven't looked into this, but you might be able to bind a listener to this event to achieve the same effect.

Comment: Great!!  Searching for <h1> headers didn't work, but a simple timeout did the trick.