# Why one can't download the web page of a tweet through an "http-get" request?

Tags: http, twitter

Through a web browser, I can view the tweet page via visiting an url like

**http://twitter.com/#!/[user-name]/status/[long-integer]**

but I can't get the correct page content through the unix command "wget". Instead, I get the welcome page of Twitter.com. How does Twitter.com distinguish a command line "get" request and a request through a browser? Thank you.

---

While I am trying to find the cause of the problem, someone else is trying to find the solution to the problem. => [Navigating / scraping hashbang links with javascript (phantomjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414152/navigating-scraping-hashbang-links-with-javascript-phantomjs)

Comment: #blah is completely client side.  It's used to scroll to an anchor on a page, though some sites use it to control AJAX requests.  The technique has a name, but I can't remember it...  Will post it if I find it.

Comment: Is there a way of simulating client side behavior through coding?

Comment: Not easily.  That would basically require making a JavaScript parser inside of your code.  However, twitter probably has an API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Navigating / scraping hashbang links with javascript (phantomjs)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414152/navigating-scraping-hashbang-links-with-javascript-phantomjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because use "hash URIs" is a stupid idea and only works in Javascript-enabled devices.

http://www.jenitennison.com/blog/node/154