# Google spreadsheet importXML works partly

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When I try to get all headers of ads from [autoscout24](http://www.autoscout24.pl/ListGN.aspx?vis=1&state=A&atype=C&make=52&model=1907&fregfrom=1999&pricefrom=1000&priceto=2000&kmfrom=50000&kmto=150000&powerscale=KW&powerfrom=100&page=1&results=20&desc=True&ustate=N,U&sort=age&mmvco=1&mmvmk0=52&mmvmd0=1907&flzh=660232123) using the xPath rule in google spreadsheet:

```
//div[@id="listOutput"]//div[@class="headcar"]/a/text()
```

The result is #NA - no data were received as a result of xPath queries.

But, when I try to get other element from page, for example "Kryteria wyszukiwania:" from the same page using the xPath rule:

```
//li/span
```

The output is correct.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please provide input XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the HTML source viewed in Chrome -- that is "view-source:http://www.autoscout24.pl/ListGN.aspx?..." not through Firebug or Chrome's Inspect Tool, div#listOutput contains only this:

```
<div id="listOutput">
    <div id="listoutput_part_one">
    </div>
    <div id="divSuperAdPlaceHolder">
        </div>
    <div id="listoutput_part_two">
    </div>
</div>
```

Whereas the source code does contains "li/span", for example:

```
        <li class="breadcrumb-item breadcrumb-first">
            <span>Kryteria wyszukiwania:</Span>
        </li>
```

The rest of elements must be built by some Javascript code run by the browser, and I doubt Google Spreadsheet interprets and executes the Javascript from the page.

Comment: Is there any way to get data that was generated by javascript?

Comment: Depends on your environment. One way is to use PhantomJS and see http://stefaanlippens.net/spider-javascript-manipulated-html-with-phantomjs or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490438/phantomjs-and-getting-modified-dom for example. See also https://groups.google.com/d/topic/phantomjs/r6cfwW6YkB4/discussion